# How do I replace the last part of a string in MS Access SQL?

Tags: sql, string, ms-access, replace

I got the following strings in one field of the Data Base:

1. Whatever MAN
2. Whatever MANAGER whatever
3. Whatever MAN whatever

I need to change the word **MAN** to **MANUAL**

I can updated strings like the 3rd case with the following code:

```
SET field_Desc = REPLACE(field_Desc , ' MAN ',' MANUAL ')
```

But due to the final space in MAN from REPLACE function the 1st case cannot be updated, so to fixe it without change words that contains MAN like the 2nd case, I tried with the following code:

```
SET field_Desc = REPLACE(field_Desc , 'MAN','MANUAL')
WHERE field_Desc LIKE '% MAN'
```

But it doesn't works, if someone can guide me, I would be very grateful.

Comment: Couldn't you right trim your field_Desc, using RTrim() and then perform the replace   REPLACE(field_Desc , 'MAN','MANUAL')?

Comment: @M.Rizzo the fields doesn't have space, I just put the spaces in the REPLACE code to match 3rd case words

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using Regular Expressions with a `whole word` pattern.

First add a reference to MicroSoft VBScript RegularExpressions, then write a public function like this:

```
Public Function RegexReplace( _
            input_string As String, _
            find_string As String, _
            replace_string As String) As String
    Dim regex As New RegExp
    regex.IgnoreCase = True
    regex.Global = True
    regex.Multiline = True
    regex.Pattern = "\b" + find_string + "\b"
    RegexReplace = regex.Replace(input_string, replace_string)
End Function
```

Usage:

```
SELECT field_Desc, RegexReplace(field_Desc , "MAN" , "MANUAL") as Replaced
FROM Table1
```

Output:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

First wrap in spaces, then replace and, finally, remove the spaces:

```
SET field_Desc = TRIM(REPLACE(' ' & field_Desc & ' ', ' MAN ',' MANUAL '))
```